# How to enable more whitespace usage via css in my ark-ui react project?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, width

I am creating a react project using the [ark-ui library](https://ark-ui.com/) and I am currently working on the [tabs](https://ark-ui.com/docs/components/tabs) component from them.

I am trying to expand the region called `data-scope=tabs data-part=list id=tabs::r1::list` to take up more whitespace as denoted on the right side of my title and buttons in the attached image.

I want to do this so I can position my title (size and stretch and margins) and subsequent tab buttons how I want.

### **Below are my project files**

package.json dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@ark-ui/react": "^1.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

TabsComponent.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Tabs } from '@ark-ui/react';
import './TabsComponent.css';

const TabsComponent = () => {
    return(
        <Tabs.Root>
            <Tabs.List>
                <div id="title">Ark UI</div>
                <Tabs.Trigger value="tab1">Tab 1</Tabs.Trigger>
                <Tabs.Trigger value="tab2">Tab 2</Tabs.Trigger>  
                <Tabs.Trigger value="tab3">Tab 3</Tabs.Trigger>  
            </Tabs.List>
            <Tabs.Content value="tab1">This is tab 1!</Tabs.Content>
            <Tabs.Content value="tab2">This is tab 2!</Tabs.Content>
            <Tabs.Content value="tab3">This is tab 3!</Tabs.Content>
        </Tabs.Root>
    );
};

export default TabsComponent;
```

TabsComponent.css

```
[data-scope='tabs'][data-part='list'] { /*Header*/
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: medium;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    /* or adjust it here */
    
  }

  [data-scope='tabs'][data-part='list'][id='tabs::r1::list'] {
    height: 100%;
    /* adjust width to use more whitespace here*/
  }

  [data-scope='tabs'][data-part='trigger'] { /*Buttons*/
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 16px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #AD5705;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.5rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.5rem;
  }

[data-scope='tabs'][data-part='content'] {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(37, 37, 37);
}

#title {
  font-size: 28px;
}
```

[Picture of open web-console showing element boundaries and subsequent white space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33bZO.png)

From the picture you can see the element with `id='tabs::r1::list` is only taking up the light blue region and the white-space is much more abundant

I've tried to adjust `[data-scope='tabs'][data-part='list']` width and also `[data-scope='tabs'][data-part='list'][id='tabs::r1::list']` width but neither work.

I've tried adjusting the display to `inline-block` for both but this results in the elements being placed vertically in a misconstrued way.

I want to simply expand the light-blue region to take up more horizontal space, so there is less whitespace (purple, dotted-line region).

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**

Made `[data-scope='tabs'][data-part='list'][id='tabs::r1::list']` `display: flex` and added `margin` to title